# Were not exist Laravel condition?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

I have the following query:

```
$clients = Client::with("types", "results", "file")->where(function ($query) use ($request) {

//

});
```

After this I check is existing GET parameter:

```
if ($request->get("status") && $request->get("status") == 1) {
    $clients->whereNotHas('result', function ($query) use ($request) {
         // TODO
    });
}
```

So, how to write conditon inside `$request->get("status") {}` that takes rows if `result` relations is empty.

I tried  `$clients->whereNotHas`. It did not help.

I tried this solution:

```
if ($request->get("status") && $request->get("status") == 2) {
      $clients->whereDoesntHave('result');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$clients = Client::with("types", "file");
if (!$request->get("status") && $request->get("status") != 2) $clients=$clients->with('results');
$clients=$clients->get()
```